# Best match using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm tackling my first project using PHP/MySQL in which I have a list of cities and ratings from 1-5 in certain categories (Food, Shopping, etc.). What I'm wanting to do is evaluate each row (each City), when a form is submitted on whether the categories are important or not.

This is how I want it to work.

Say, for example:
1. **Chicago** Food: 4, Shopping: 4, Nightlife: 4
2. **New York** Food: 4, Shopping: 5, Nightlife: 5
3. **Boston** Food: 5, Shopping: 4, Nightlife: 3
(the ratings are just for example)

And the user says that Food isn't important. Therefore the code will only evaluate Shopping and Nightlife... New York ends with 10, Chicago with 8 and Boston with 7.

As I have a list of around 35-40 cities that I want to evaluate on each category (if the user deems it "important") dynamically, and the winner will be the highest number at the end of the evaluation.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this? I have the table built in MySQL with all the ratings, just need to write the code out now.

What I've tried: bringing in all of the values using arrays, but I've found it difficult to loop through each of the rows... help!

Comment: Is this supposed to filter search results or _sort_ them or what?

Comment: I brought in all of the data using arrays. So I have Food, Shopping, Nightlife arrays. Got kinda stuck at that point in evaluating each of the arrays.

Comment: @NathanFrancy So this script is supposed to _import_ data into a database and give each category a "score" based on some criteria?

Comment: I'm sorry @mmmshuddup if I'm not being clear enough. I'm basically performing a compatibility match on the cities I have in my database next to my ratings in each category. But, realizing that each user is going to have different needs, you can choose what is most important to you. This is supposed to be a "Where should I go on vacation?" helper.

Comment: @mmmshuddup yes. Each city will have a score at the end of the script and will have a winner by which one has the highest score.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this task with just a little bit of PHP code and an appropiate SQL statement.
Here is a possible solution:

```
$important_cat = $_POST['categories']; //which is an array
$sql = "SELECT city, sum(".implode(' + ',$important_cat).") AS cat
        FROM tbl
        ORDER BY cat DESC";
//query sql
```

Comment: How are you sure that _this_ is what the OP wanted?  I still don't fully understand what his needs are..

Comment: I don't know exactly what he wants, but I think he wants to get the cities ordered by the categories which are relevant for an user. With this SQL statement he will get them. I haven't made any suggestion what he can do with the result... .

Comment: Basically you save your relevant categories in an array ($important_cat). And then you query the database... . The sum(...) in the SELECT part, summarizes all of the relevant categories and you get them in your result. (The field is called cat)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming database tables similar to this (at least, they *should* be normalized in this fashion):

```
city ( id, name );
category ( id, name );
rating ( city_id, category_id, rating );
```

... with an array of interests similar to this:

```
$interests = array(
    'Food',
    'Shopping'
);
```

... the following sql:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
          city.name as city,
          GROUP_CONCAT( category.name || ": " || rating.rating, ", " ) as ratings,
          SUM( rating.rating ) as totalRating
        FROM
          rating
        JOIN
          city
          ON city.id = rating.city_id
        JOIN
          category
          ON category.id = rating.category_id
        WHERE
          category.name IN( ' . implode( ',', array_map( array( $db, 'quote' ), $interests ) ) . ' )
        GROUP BY
          city.name
        ORDER BY
          totalRating DESC';
```

*(I assumed the use of [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), utilizing [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) for escaping here, but substitute the callback `array( $db, 'quote' )` with whatever quoting/escape mechanism your mysql library offers)*

... will yield a result set similar to this (I've populated random rating data for my example):

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'name' => 'Chicago',
    'ratings' => 'Food: 3, Shopping: 3',
    'totalRating' => '6'
  ),
  1 => array (
    'name' => 'New York',
    'ratings' => 'Food: 1, Shopping: 4',
    'totalRating' => '5'
  ),
  2 => array (
    'name' => 'Seattle',
    'ratings' => 'Food: 4, Shopping: 1',
    'totalRating' => '5'
  ),
  3 => array (
    'name' => 'Los Angeles',
    'ratings' => 'Food: 2, Shopping: 2',
    'totalRating' => '4'
  ),
  4 => array (
    'name' => 'Boston',
    'ratings' => 'Food: 1, Shopping: 2',
    'totalRating' => '3'
  ),
  5 => array (
    'name' => 'San Francisco',
    'ratings' => 'Food: 1, Shopping: 1',
    'totalRating' => '2'
  )
)
```

If you only need the first result, append `LIMIT 1` to the sql query.

This should give you an idea of how to go about accomplishing what you want.

**Above all:** let MySQL do all the work (filtering, sorting) — not PHP.